# No logro entender donde tengo una variable inicializada, segun Valgrind

Tags: c

Estuve buscando una solucion para un error que muestra Valgrind, y he visto de todo un poco, pero no logro entender, la idea es la siguiente, invocar una funcion que toma un valor int y devuelve un char* (cadena de caracteres) que dice "El numero es %d.".
Segun lei, el error apunta a que hay una variable inicializada, pero no entiendo cual es.

**El codigo es**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* cadena(int numero);


char* cadena(int numero){
    char prim[15];
    for (int i = 0; i<15; ++i){prim[i]={'\0'};} 
    sprintf(prim, "El numero es %d", numero);
    char* puntero = prim;
    return puntero;
}

int main()
{
    int numero = 2;
    printf("%s.\n", cadena(2));
    return 0;
}
```

**Y el error es**

```
==18031== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18031== at 0x484ED19: strlen (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18031== by 0x48E2DB0: __vfprintf_internal (vfprintf-internal.c:1517)
==18031== by 0x48CC81E: printf (printf.c:33)
==18031== by 0x109237: main (in /home/eduanx/Escritorio/A)
```

Comment: ¿por qué estás asignando `{'\0'}` a la posición del arreglo en lugar de solo asignar `\0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *el error apunta a que hay una variable inicializada*

No, lee bien:

> ```
> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
> ```

*Uninitialised* significa "*no inicializada*", no significa "*inicializada"*.

---

No necesito valgrind para ver cuál es el error en tu código: estás devolviendo una variable local de función, esa variable dejará de existir en cuanto la función termine; probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* cadena(int numero);


char* cadena(int numero){
    // Pedir memoria dinámica, esta memoria sobrevive a la función
    char *prim = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
    sprintf(prim, "El numero es %d", numero);
    return prim;
}

int main()
{
    int numero = 2;
    // Guardar el puntero, si se pierde no se puede liberar.
    char *texto = cadena(2);
    printf("%s.\n", texto);
    // Liberar el puntero con memoria dinámica.
    free(texto);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Al final lo que hice fue utilizar 'new' en lugar de 'malloc' debido a que dentro de las codiciones de hacer el codigo, no estaba permitido usar otra libreria que no fueran 'stdio.h y string.h', pero me sirvio un monton de guia y quedo solucionado.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si estás usando `new`/`delete` en lugar de `malloc`/`free` significa que estás programando en [tag:c++], no en [tag:c]... lo que implica que no debes usar las cabeceras `stdio.h` ni `string.h` (que son de C) ni `sprintf`, ni `pintf` por el mismo motivo.

Comment: En realidad, en donde estoy estudiando, usamos C junto a unas cosas de C++, el 'new' y 'delete', declaraciones de tipos (como en C++) para registros y enumerados, pasaje por referencia, y el tipo de datos bool.
Tal vez debí agregar eso al post, mi error.

Comment: Siento decirte que te están enseñando mal. Si usas `new`, `delete` y referencias no estás usando [tag:c] pues ese lenguaje carece de esas características.